# C# Excel Automation - How to copy a row from one worksheet to a new worksheet in an existing workbok?

Tags: c#, excel

I'm new to Excel Automation. Programming in C# in Visual Studio 2022 and have created a COM dependency on Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and added "using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;" to my Windows Forms application.

I can create an Excel Application, open the existing Excel Workbook and create a new Worksheet without issue. However, I'm trying to copy the Header Row1 (cells A1:AR2) from an existing sheet into the new sheet and get an error code Message = "0x800A03EC". This error code is not very helpful and a lookup seems to indicate a named variable is not found. Here's the code:

```
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet, xlWorksheet2;
    Excel.Range xlRange;
           xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(newWorkbookName);
           xlWorksheet2 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Worksheets.Add();
           xlWorksheet2.Name = "Excel Opportunity Import Te (2)";
            // Copy Header row from original sheet to new sheet
            xlWorksheet2 = xlWorkbook.Worksheets["Excel Opportunity Import Te (2)"];
            xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets["Excel Opportunity Import Templa"];
            // xlWorksheet2.Rows["1"].CopyFrom(xlWorksheet.Rows["1"]); 
            xlWorksheet.Copy(xlWorksheet.Range["A1:AR1"], xlWorksheet2.Range["A2:AR2"]);
            xlWorkbook.SaveAs(newWorkbookName);
            xlWorkbook.Close();
            xlApp.Quit();
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
```

Also, I saw multiple examples searching of using the sheet.rows[n].CopyFrom method which is commented out above. If I un-comment it, intellisense does not raise any issue, but upon execution there is an error indicating that the method does not exist.

see above code sample

Answer (score 0):

I've also used the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` before but I quickly noticed that it doesn't work great. So I searched for another option and found the `PicoXLSX` plugin with the NuGet Packages.
You can easily create new xlsx-files and add `Worksheets` and works fine with the `ExcelDataReader` plugin.
With those plugins you don't need to install Office also. So if you install your program on a computer which hasn't office, it runs just fine.